# <!{CDATA[]]> and <ELEMENT> in a xml element

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm currently trying to write a DTD for an XML file.

In the xml I came across this type of things :

```
<CHAMP NAME="JBRTHDTC" DOMAIN="DM" DB="YES:CRF" TYPE="JOUR" FORCED="YES" AFFICHE="YES">
    <![CDATA[ Date de naissance: ]]>
    <MESSAGE><![CDATA[Date de naissance (Jour)]]></MESSAGE>
</CHAMP>
```

Is it ok to have CDATA and a xml element inside another?

If so, how can I manage to write it in DTD? Like

```
ELEMENT CHAMP (MESSAGE?|CDATA??)>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare `CHAMP` as a mixed content model.

This means that `CHAMP` can contain either `#PCDATA` (parsed character data) or `MESSAGE`. (You can still have `CDATA` sections in the mixed content model.)

This has to be declared a certain way, so you won't be able to limit the number of occurrences of `MESSAGE`. It's zero or more `#PCDATA` or `MESSAGE` in any order.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE CHAMP [
<!ELEMENT CHAMP (#PCDATA|MESSAGE)*>
<!ATTLIST CHAMP
        NAME    CDATA #IMPLIED
        DOMAIN  CDATA #IMPLIED
        DB      CDATA #IMPLIED
        TYPE    CDATA #IMPLIED
        FORCED  CDATA #IMPLIED
        AFFICHE CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT MESSAGE (#PCDATA)>
]>
<CHAMP NAME="JBRTHDTC" DOMAIN="DM" DB="YES:CRF" TYPE="JOUR" FORCED="YES" AFFICHE="YES">
    <![CDATA[ Date de naissance: ]]>
    <MESSAGE><![CDATA[Date de naissance (Jour)]]></MESSAGE>
</CHAMP>
```