# XmlDeserialize cdata and its siblings

Tags: c#, traversal, cdata, xml-deserialization

I'm in the process of deserializing into C# objects a custom inflexible XML schema to traverse and migrate the data within.

A brief example:

```
  <Source>
    ...
    <Provider>
      <![CDATA[read 1]]>
      <Identifier><![CDATA[read 2]]></Identifier>
      <IdentificationScheme><![CDATA[read 3]]></IdentificationScheme>
    </Provider>
    ...
  </Source>
```

I'm looking the deserialize the Provider element with the first CDATA element value, `read 1`, and it's sibling element values too, `read 2` and `read 3`.

Using http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ it produces the following objects:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Provider")]
public class Provider
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Identifier")]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "IdentificationScheme")]
    public string IdentificationScheme { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Source")]
public class Source
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Provider")]
    public Provider Provider { get; set; }
}
```

But it fails to account for the the CDATA value, in fact I think deserializing it like this the value would not be reachable.

I think this maybe also be related to the XmlDeserializer to use, I was planning on `RestSpharp`'s (as it's a library to the website already) or `System.Xml.Link.XDocument`, but I'm not sure whether either can handle this scenario?

In my searches I couldn't find an example either, but stack did suggest this [<!{CDATA[]]> and <ELEMENT> in a xml element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103203/cdata-and-element-in-a-xml-element) that is precisely the same schema option.

Thanks so much for any help in advance,

**EDIT 1**
As far as I can tell the `[XmlText]` is the solution required, as pointed out in Marc Gravell's answer below, but it does not work/is implemented on RestSharp's XmlDeserializer, but further testing would be required to ascertain that for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDATA is essentially just escaping syntax and is handled by most readers. What you are looking for is:

```
[XmlText]
public string WhateverThisIs { get; set; }
```

on the object that has raw content. By adding that to `Provider`, `WhateverThisIs` gets the value of `"read 1"`. The other 2 properties already deserialize correctly as `"read 2"` and `"read 3"` without you having to do anything.

For reference, everything here would behave *almost* the same without the CDATA (there are some whitespace issues):

```
<Provider>
  read 1
  <Identifier>read 2</Identifier>
  <IdentificationScheme>read 3</IdentificationScheme>
</Provider>
```

Comment: yah it's called mixed content, just found out via depper searching, however the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/a/25997011/271433 is an array, i assume that as long as there is only one CDATA your answer will work?

Comment: @PedroCosta forget about CDATA - that isn't the problem here (see my edit); but yes, this will work fine as long as you only have one *random piece of content in there*.

Comment: ummm, everything but the `Text` property is filled in with RestSharp's Deserializer `xmlDeserializer.Deserialize<List<Av>>(response)`, time to try the default one :D

Comment: using default works a treat :D `List<Av> results = ((EFG)serializer.Deserialize(reader)).Av;` but did have to be stricter with the root node hence the `EFG`

Comment: sorry should clarify, `EFG` is document root `AV` is the node that has a `Source` and `Provider` like the schema in the question, comments were just regarding the Deserialization method that the answer supports.